# Imposing LIMIT on UNION

Tags: mysql, mariadb

We are working with some legacy code that is using a sub-optimally normalized DB.  The problem that we are trying to solve is best described with an illustrative example.
`hi_priority` and `lo_priority` are two tables that have the same schema, as defined below:

```
CREATE TABLE hi_priority
(
  id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(16),
  col1 VARCHAR(16),
  col2 INT,

  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);



CREATE TABLE lo_priority
(
  id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(16),
  col1 VARCHAR(16),
  col2 INT,

  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

In each table there is a 1:1 mapping between the `name` and `col2`.

The idea is to potentially `SELECT name, col1, col2` from both tables but limit the total number of distinct names (let's say 7 for our illustrative example), subject to the following constraints:

- Preference is to be given to entries from `hi_priority` table over entries from `lo_priority` tables.
- For example, if there are 15 distinct names in `hi_priority` table,
  we will select all rows with 7 names from `hi_priority` table,
  ordered by `col2`.
- If there are 5 distinct names in `hi_priority`
  table, we select all rows with those 5 names and on top of that we
  select all rows with 2 distinct names from `lo_priority` table,
  ordered by `col2`
- If there are some entries in both the
  `hi_priority` table and the `lo_priority` table, we select entries
  only from the `hi_priority` table

---

Let us assume that the tables are populated as follows:

```
INSERT INTO hi_priority(name, col1, col2) VALUES('john', 'kl7y5tis4yh4', 1), ('john', 'tiid6iywq02k', 1), 
('john', 'detawgsxz615', 1), ('amy', 'i6u4hhc1trjk', 2), ('amy', 'wdpt0t5vtmbt', 2),
('amy', '87z5wgdfztwl', 2), ('amy', 'oj98jjdpb5yv', 2), ('steve', 'hllaazonflf0', 3),
('steve', '0h22y66kq3ow', 3), ('steve', 'o04ksti7di60', 3), ('steve', '3qlylbzqfr51', 3),
('steve', 'wmisshywtb12', 3), ('bob', 'ku8wpf7d6ta9', 3), ('bob', '6t7mn60g0g18', 3),
('bob', 'qv0s7ho3jku6', 3), ('bob', '5qgz7dznzwvn', 3), ('bob', 'mm76nhimm6fu', 3),
('bob', 'k7nlpksc55t2', 3), ('oliver', 'gvf9kjewpj7h', 4), ('oliver', '24w5s30w5te6', 4);


INSERT INTO lo_priority(name, col1, col2) VALUES('doug', 'j205tzrsfmax', 11), ('doug', '0w7rcazbh6es', 11),
('doug', '6xswf8frsjaw', 11), ('john', 'iw7d14vtysz2', 2), ('john', '6lg667dygaz1', 2),
('john', '83uk5dcobpu5', 2), ('john', 'tl8cpzatv0n9', 2), ('mike', '2dsarwozpmci', 3),
('mike', 'hinn6w03wdib', 3), ('mike', '4sxbgyacmjob', 3), ('mike', 'm4q13ln9gctj', 3),
('mike', 'pnip9c8cejo9', 3), ('steve', 'faff9p9v96x4', 4), ('steve', 'd5mxqpd3k8zi', 4),
('martha', 'bxggn5t6d2xn', 8), ('martha', 't05mi47i4n6l', 8), ('martha', 'p30wmw2o6nty', 8),
('martha', 'wip6efajt9yv', 8);
```

---

```
The expected output is:  
+--------+------------+------+
| name   | col1       | col2 |
+--------+------------+------+
| john   | kl7y5tis4y |    1 |
| john   | tiid6iywq0 |    1 |
| john   | detawgsxz6 |    1 |
| amy    | oj98jjdpb5 |    2 |
| amy    | 87z5wgdfzt |    2 |
| amy    | wdpt0t5vtm |    2 |
| amy    | i6u4hhc1tr |    2 |
| bob    | k7nlpksc55 |    3 |
| bob    | mm76nhimm6 |    3 |
| bob    | 5qgz7dznzw |    3 |
| bob    | qv0s7ho3jk |    3 |
| bob    | 6t7mn60g0g |    3 |
| bob    | ku8wpf7d6t |    3 |
| steve  | wmisshywtb |    3 |
| steve  | 3qlylbzqfr |    3 |
| steve  | o04ksti7di |    3 |
| steve  | 0h22y66kq3 |    3 |
| steve  | hllaazonfl |    3 |
| mike   | 4sxbgyacmj |    3 |
| mike   | pnip9c8cej |    3 |
| mike   | m4q13ln9gc |    3 |
| mike   | hinn6w03wd |    3 |
| mike   | 2dsarwozpm |    3 |
| oliver | gvf9kjewpj |    4 |
| oliver | 24w5s30w5t |    4 |
| martha | bxggn5t6d2 |    8 |
| martha | t05mi47i4n |    8 |
| martha | p30wmw2o6n |    8 |
| martha | wip6efajt9 |    8 |
+--------+------------+------+
```

- Amy, Bob and Oliver are only present in `hi_priority` table and will be selected.
- Mike and Martha are only present in `lo_priority` table and will be selected.
- John and Steve are present in both `hi_priority` table and `lo_priority` table but will be selected only from `hi_priority` table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
WITH
cte_hi AS ( SELECT DISTINCT name, hi_priority.col2, 1 priority 
            FROM hi_priority
            ORDER BY col2, name LIMIT 7 ),
cte_lo AS ( SELECT DISTINCT lo_priority.name, lo_priority.col2, 2 priority 
            FROM lo_priority
            LEFT JOIN cte_hi USING (name)
            WHERE cte_hi.name IS NULL
            ORDER BY col2, name LIMIT 7 ),
cte_total AS ( SELECT * FROM cte_hi
               UNION ALL
               SELECT * FROM cte_lo
               ORDER BY priority, col2 LIMIT 7 )
SELECT hi_priority.*
FROM cte_total
JOIN hi_priority USING (name)
WHERE priority = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT lo_priority.*
FROM cte_total
JOIN lo_priority USING (name)
WHERE priority = 2
ORDER BY col2, name, id
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4e8be1c4777c22698115abd0625078c4)

Answer (score 2):

The way to give preference to one part of a `UNION` is

```
( SELECT 1 AS priority, ... FROM hi_priority ORDER BY .. LIMIT 7 )
UNION ALL
( SELECT 2 AS priority, ... FROM lo_priority ORDER BY .. LIMIT 7 )
ORDER BY priority, ...   -- Note: start with `priority`, then rest of ordering
LIMIT 7
```

Note that `ORDER BY .. LIMIT` on each part of the `UNION` and another `ORDER BY ..` on the end of the `UNION`.

If you also have `OFFSET`, it gets a little more complex.  I discuss it here:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#or